# iOS: How will I drop a placemark at user's location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkplacemark

This is my code to recenter map to user's location in iOS. This method works fine, but the problem I am having is dropping a placemark on the user's current location. I am new to using placemark and will appreciate it if someone help me out.

```
- (IBAction)recenterMapToUserLocation:(id)sender {
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

region.span = span;
region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: `[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];` not a placemark but apple way of showing user's current location

Comment: did u got it? @user3192186

Comment: study about MKAnnotation

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the user's location (and keep it updating when they move). Or place a pin where the user is right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop a pin on the user's location, all you have to do is tell the mapView to show the user's location:

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

That should do it!